# I need stream camera feed using react-native

Tags: react-native, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I need to stream camera and microphone feed using react native. I need to open the camera and get the stream in real time.

Comment: had you any success?

Comment: I Didn't tried. But i think the answer might work

Answer (score 1):

You need `react-native-fetch-blob` and `Tailer` package. It has a function called RNFetchBlob.fs.readStream which can be used to stream a file.

The step by step tutorial is here

https://medium.com/react-native-training/build-youtube-alike-livestreams-with-react-native-8dde24adf543